# Corona sdk: Scoring

Tags: iphone, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a simple corona sdk game but I can't get it working.
I wanne make a score text field but I have a lot of problems.

The functions:

```
function points(num)
 addPoints()
 score = score + num
 scoreTxt.text = "hoi"
 scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
end

function addPoints()
num = math.random(100, 350)
end
```

Some other information:

```
score = 50;
num = 50;
scoreTxt = display.newText ("Score:", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 20)
scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
scoreTxt.x = display.screenOriginX + 10
scoreTxt.y = display.screenOriginX + 5
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your exact problem...? :O

Comment: Have you tried `ScrollViewWidget` ?

Comment: My problem is that my score just says 0, it doesn't change.

Comment: I haven't tried ScrollViewWidget what is it?

Comment: Already figured out how to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function points()
 num=addPoints()
 score = score + num
 scoreTxt.text = "hoi"
 scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
end

function addPoints()
num = math.random(100, 350)
return num
end
```

How can you get value from that function.Try like this.